# What's the probability of a 7 digits phone number with 4 different digits being the correct one.

Tags: probability

So, Ben wants to call Jon but he doesn't remember his number. He only recalls that the phone number has 4 different digits. Ben calls a number; what's the probability that he is talking with Jon?

Comment: Try to compute how many different phone numbers there are. If their number is $n$, since only one of them is the correct one, the probability will be $1/n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of hints.
Let $A,B,C,D$ be four different digits. Answer the following three questions:

- How many occurences of each digit can there be. We know that each one occurs at least one time, and in total there are seven digits.
- How many seven letter words can be made out of $A,B,C,D$, with occurrences as above?
- In how many ways can we assign different digit values to $A,B,C,D$ for each of the above cases?

Solution:

> Call $\#A$ the number of occurrences of $A$ in a number/word. Suppose, without loss of generality $\#A \geq \#B \geq \#C \geq \#D \geq 1$. We also have $\#A + \#B + \#C + \#D = 7$. This gives us three possible cases
>
>  1. $\#A=4, \#B=1, \#C=1, \#D=1$
>  2. $\#A=3, \#B=2, \#C=1, \#D=1$
>  3. $\#A=2, \#B=2, \#C=2, \#D=1$
>
>  Now let's see how many different 7-letter words can we make with the above occurrences.
>
>  1. $AAAABCD$ can be permuted into $\frac{7!}{4!1!1!1!}=210$ different words
>  2. $AAABBCD$ can be permuted into $\frac{7!}{3!2!1!1!}=420$ different words
>  3. $AABBCCD$ can be permuted into $\frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}=630$ different words
>
>  Finally let's see in how many **different** ways can we assign digits to the letters. Different is bolded because we have to be careful. For example in the first case assigning 1 to A and 2 to B is different from assigning 2 to A and 1 to B, but assigning 1 to B and 2 to C will be repeated in some permutation where we assign 2 to B and 1 to C.
>
>  1. There are $10$ digit choices for $A$ and then $9 \choose 3$ for $B,C,D$, in total 840 assignments.
>  2. There are $10$ choices for $A$, 9 choices for $B$ and $8 \choose 2$ for $C,D$, in total 2520 assignments.
>  3. There are $10$ choices for $D$ and $9 \choose 3$ for $A,B,C$, in total 840 assignments.
>
>
> Summing up everything together we have
>
>  1. 210 * 840 = 176400 different numbers
>  2. 420 * 2520 = 1058400 different numbers
>  3. 630 * 840 = 529200 different numbers
>
>  In total 1763600 different 7-digit telephone numbers containing four different digits, so the probability of a random number being equal to this one is 1/1763600.